# Passing ggplot2's aes_string() a string via lapply doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've written a function that requires one argument and is supposed to output a plot. The argument it takes is the variable to be plotted on the y axis as a character. Here is some example data:

```
df_year <- data.frame(year = c(2000, 2001), V1 = c(1.7,2.6))
df_year_speaker <- data.frame(year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001), 
                              speaker = c("Smith", "House", "Smith", "House"),
                              V1 = c(1.5,2,2.3,3), 
                              partyaffil = c("rep", "dem", "rep", "dem"))
```

And here my plot function:

```
require(ggplot2)
plot_fct <- function(means_year = df_year,
                     means_year_speaker = df_year_speaker,
                     x="year",
                     y="V1"){
  ggplot()+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#778aff","#ff6f54"))+ #blue,red
    geom_line(data = means_year, aes_string(x, y),
                color = "#212121")+
    geom_point(data = means_year_speaker,  aes_string(x, y))+
    geom_label(data = means_year_speaker, aes_string(x, y,label="speaker",
                                                       fill = "partyaffil"),
                                                       color = "#343434")
}
```

When I run my function directly, it works just fine:

```
plot_fct(y = "V1")
```

But when I call it via `lapply` I get an error:

```
> lapply(list(A = "V1"), FUN = plot_fct)
  Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character
```

Running traceback revealed that the error is in `fortify.default(data)`.
Any ideas on what's wrong or how I can pass strings to my function via `lapply`?

Comment: Redefine the function `plot_fct` with `y` as its first argument. Then lapply works correctly to the first argument that is y, not means_year.

Comment: I suspect you're really after `facet_grid`

Comment: Can ´facet_grid´ produce seperat plots? I want to plot >90 variables with this function, so having them all in one would not work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it is not clear which parameter of the function has to be set to the single values of the list.

If you change the signature of the function by removing the default parameter of y to

```
plot_fct <- function(y, means_year = df_year,
                 means_year_speaker = df_year_speaker,
                 x="year")
```

it should work as you intended.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had this idea and tried ´lapply(y = list(A = "V1"), FUN = plot_fct)´ but after receiving ´Error in lapply(y = list(A = "V1"), FUN = plot_fct) : 
  argument "X" is missing, with no default´ didn't pursue it further.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you call `plot_fct(y = "V1")` you are passing `V1` to the `y=` parameter in particular. When using `lapply`, by default it will go to the first parameter, and `y` is not the first parameter. YOu can do

```
lapply(list(A = "V1"), FUN = function(y) plot_fct(y=y))
```

Comment: This works just as well as the other answer, but Frank was a few seconds ealier. Thanks a lot still!